# How do automatically update ingress rules?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-ingress

We have stateful services that should be reachable under different URLs. The ingress mapping in the ingress rules should look something like this:

```
 - myApp/instance1 
   // route to service 1
 - myApp/instance2
   // route to service 2
```

Now at any point we may start a new `instance3`. How do we adapt the ingress rules?

- Can we do this automatically using an ingress controller?
- If so, do you have any idea which ingress controller supports this?
- What should I read to understand this issue better?

Comment: If they are different applications (e.g. serves different traffic), then you should deploy them as multiple different deployments, not use the instances (replicas) for different things.

Comment: each `instance` will be its own deployment and each instance will have its own service.

Comment: ok, sounds like all is good. You can just add the new service to the Ingress manifest and apply it. If that does not work, you need to clarify your question and show the Ingress manifest.

Comment: I understand, but I would like to do this automatically, since there may be frequent changes. My thought was to write an operator that watches the services in this cluster and then changes the ingress. However I hoped that there is a better solution to this

Comment: You can do that. It is unclear what your question is about at the moment.

Comment: I think my question is "is there a better way to do this?" and "do any of the ingress controllers already provide this logic?"

Comment: If you edit the yaml and apply, it will work. All kubernetes controllers work that way.

Comment: I think you would be better off by having a manifest file for each app - but share the gateway. So e.g. for each app you have a few manifests, Deployment, Service and Ingress (perhaps more things like ConfigMap and Secrets). This way, you don't share any files between apps.

Answer (score 0):

Few options which you can use instead of writing your own operator

**Init container** :
Adding init container to your Deployment which will add the desired rule to your Ingress.

**Probes** :
Add a post-start probe which will be executed once your pod is running and kicking will update the Ingress rules.

**CronJob** :
Add a CronJob which will "scan" for changes and will update the Ingress again

Comment: None of these are good practices.

Comment: Those are hacks which we can do currently to automate your use case and if you need best practice then you should probably write your own controller to do it as we don't have anything out of the box doing it.

Comment: I disagree with that. It is better to keep the Yaml manifests in a Git repo, and track version of changes. No operator is needed for that.

Comment: Sorry, seems like you are confused here. I was talking about updating the ingress rules automatically when a new instance is added